# Joomla's extent for a custom but yet simple web social platform

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

I know Joomla as a CMS manager, which is a system that manages different contents (texts, media,... etc).
But people tend to say: **ALWAYS** use joomla for your pro projects... bla bla

Let's imagine I need to do the following:

- A web site where registered users post quotes (like in chucknorrisfacts.com for example), quotes are moderated, then published to people. And quotes have comments (from registered users).

How would Joomla help me **easily** building such a website ?

Because I think I can develop it very fast by starting from the scratch, but in another hand I'm very very interested in using Joomla as a base in order to learn it, and experience CMS methodology.

The Joomla administration console helps putting components on the websites and all that stuff, but what happens when we do need to store user input, submit it to users moderation, then publish this content and allow comments on it ? Does this require Joomla plugin development ? Or is there another road that could be taken...
My question might seem noobish, that's because this is going to be my first experience with a CMS though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. Where to start. First, the Joomla core does not support all of the requirements as it does not have a built in commenting system. Next, plenty of "pro" sites use Joomla, Wordpress, and Drupal. Big sites with big traffic and big budgets. More and more corporate sites are going looking to OS CMS, they have really come a long way in the last couple of years. Last, Joomla 1.0 stopped being supported a LONG time ago. Since 1.0, 1.5 released and had 22 updates, and 1.6 released earlier this month.

As for the original question, Joomla would be an excellent choice for the requirements described because it can easily be done with just K2. You can set up a specific content type for quotes, assign registered users as authors that can submit content, and turn on commenting for registered users. All of this is built in to K2 without any modifications.

Comment: That's what I call an answer ! Thank you very much dear Brent

Comment: Thanks, but I just realized I missed the most important part of the answer. I am sure you have already found it, but here is the link anyway - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction/8061

Answer (score 0):

I think Joomla does support that from core.

The quote of using joomla on pro sites is WRONG.

The real pro sites are custom build or use a professional CMS.
The semi pro sites use joomla (or any other OSS CMS).

Why?
Joomla is (at least the 1.0 version) slow, and not friendly to your server.
Also Joomla is vulnerable to attacks from script kiddies.
Not as unsafe as Wordpress though...

Comment: thank you for your opinion. Even though, I wouldn't use Wordpress for this purpose, I hate it when use-specific systems tries to catch up with other use cases... Like WP is for blogging and gets bloated by too much additions to support other things like simply building an E-Commerce. I'd rather use a teeth-brush to brush my teeth and a paintbrush for painting. But anyway, what CMS would you suggest to replace Joomla ? (in the scope of what I want to do of course). Kr

Comment: Also, when you say Joomla supports that from core, what is your statement based on? did you read something about it? if so, how does this work? just activate a module that does the whole thing? It's blurry to me